# Op-amp amplifier for Hall sensor: grounding

Tags: operational-amplifier, ground, hall-effect

[image: Symbolic diagram of circuit being used]
I built a simple LM741 non-inverting amplifier with a fixed gain of 3.1x and verified it works for a simple +0.3 VDC input on pin 3. It uses a dual power supply consisting of two 9V batteries in series to give me a good 0 V ground reference.

I want to add a Hall effect sensor with operating voltage at 4.5V and added a voltage divider as shown (R1 + R2). I verify that I get ca +4.3v.  I connected the [A1302](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/2135881.pdf) Hall sensor as shown following the pin-out specs. I connected the output lead from the Hall sensor (which my voltmeter says is producing +1.0 to +1.4 V). When I connect it to pin 3, I get a fixed output of -8.05 V.

I know that without the Hall sensor the opamp gives the right amplification and voltage with a variable test input, but it only provides a fixed negative (inverted!) output when the Hall sensor input is added, which should vary as I move the magnet across the sensor. I know the sensor works because I have independently tested it. The expected output range of +3 to +4.2 volts is indide the -9 to +9v range set by the rails. I cant seem to figure out why this doesnt work!

Note: I am an astrophysicist not an EE!

Comment: See my edited version and the included diagram

Comment: I should also replace R2 with a Zener (5.1 V) and adapt R1 as needed. Be aware also of opamp offset.

Comment: The voltage at pin a of A1202 is "too" low, the minimum recommended is 4.5 V min -> 5 V.

Comment: Have you looked at the voltages with a scope? It might be oscillating. You should put bypass capacitors (100-500 nF) on the power supply rails and the + input of the op-amp, with a series resistor around 1k.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add a Hall effect sensor with operating voltage at 4.5V and added a voltage divider as shown (R1 + R2). I verify that I get ca +4.3v.

Voltage ok.

> I connected the A1302 Hall sensor as shown following the pin-out specs.

Did you forget that the A1302 current supply is approximately 10-11 mA under 5V?
In this case, the voltage you measure is nomore right. It is something like 2.25 V now.
A1302 is not well supplied, so all can happen.

[image]

You should use something like this for supplying A1302.

[image]

Comment: Antonio51----Wow! Thanks so much, Ill try this.  BTW, my batteries are now at B1=8.65 and B2=8.4 volts so with R1=330 ohms and R2=220 ohms across the first battery my voltage divider produces +5.1volts unloaded, but when I attach the A1302 it drops to 3.8V. The output from Pin6 to ground is now between +5.0 and +5.3V depending on whether the test magnet is off or on the sensor....This confirms what you were saying about the dip in the vvoltage supply! I am at least now getting an output from Pin6 that varies with the magnet and isnt 'pinned' near the + rail voltage like before. Getting close!